# Google Colab files.download() Stability

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have been using Google Colab as a lightweight, easy to use, and conveniently accessible Jupyter notebook for a small python script that automates a few reports I create for work.

I am uploading/downloading xlsx/csv files using Googles out-of-the-box `files.upload()` and `files.download()` methods. Unfortunately I have found great inconsistency in their reliability. Every so often `files.download()` will throw a `TypeError: Failed to fetch` and crash without downloading the file. To negate this I used an *extremely* hacky try-except block that makes a few attempts if the first fails.

Here's that code below:

```
for i in range(5):
  try:
    files.download('{0}.xlsx'.format(today_fi_name))

  except TypeError:
    # Let's try that again...
    print("Download of new file failed... Trying again... x{0}".format(i+1))

  else:
    break
```

Can anyone recommend a more reliable means of downloading files from the online notebook?

Comment: This seems like a worthwhile bug report. Have you filed an [issue](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues) with debugging information when the fetch error occurs? (e.g., HTTP response codes, or Javascript console errors.)

Comment: I tried to reproduce this issue by [repeatedly downloading a random 5 MB file](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GMQW3dHviafhu7KZleb1IJ4JWOImqRVi) but I didn't encounter a fetch error. Are you using a larger file? Or, a browser other than Chrome?

Comment: I have not yet filed a bug report, but I probably will the next time I encounter the error. The file isn't too large (depending on what we consider large), but it's a roughly 2,000 row by 20 column plain text .xlsx file around no more than a few mb if my memory serves me correct.